# get document from compare editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How to get document from compare editor? I have got CompareViewerSwitchingPane, but I don't know how to extract document for left and right pane.

I need it to get text that is displayed in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way how one could get document for his CompareEditorInput. There are different kinds of compare inputs: the one that goes to CompareEditor and the ones that go to CompareEditor viewers.

I was so close with CompareUI.getDocument(Object), but first time I found it I gave it CompareEditorInput and it returned me `null` instead of a reasonable object (may be for intermediate developer there is no mysteries, but not for me). And I put it aside thinking that this method does not work.

Thanks to [aphex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220522/aphex) due to which I gave a bit more attention to `CompareUI.getDocument(Object)` and it stroke me with an idea: hey, why not to try to pass DiffNode instead of a CompareEditor and finally it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The following code example shows how to get the left and right compare editor Document (and the text in the document):

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IEditorPart editorPart = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
CompareEditorInput compareEditorInput = (CompareEditorInput) editorPart.getEditorInput();
ICompareInput compareInput = (ICompareInput) compareEditorInput.getCompareResult();
ITypedElement leftTypedElement = compareInput.getLeft();
ITypedElement rightTypedElement = compareInput.getRight();
IDocument leftDocument = CompareUI.getDocument(leftTypedElement);
IDocument rightDocument = CompareUI.getDocument(rightTypedElement);
String left = leftDocument.get();
String right = rightDocument.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the EditorInput, which extends CompareEditorInput. From the Pluginclass you can retrieve the current active editor using:

```
getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
```

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F) you can see how the compare editor works and how you fill the compare editor with the needed information to work.

EDIT: Link fixed.

Comment: link is broken. There is currently no text in this page, you can search for this page title in other pages or edit this page.

Comment: The editor input does not have current changes made in the editor. And I need them, they are stored in the IDocument instance which I cant retrieve.

Comment: If I could turn CompareEDitorInput into documents. There is a `CompareUI.getDocument(Object)`, do you what it is for?